# How to get access of state in js file VUEX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I would like to get access to the `state` property `currentUser` of `vuex` in `user.js` to use it in `auth.js` but it doesn't work if I write: `store.state.currentUser.uid ===` ...

And I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.

What is there missing in the code?

the tree:

```
src
 store
   user
    |>user.js
    |>mutations.js
   index.js
 auth.js
```

user.js:

```
 const state = {
   profile: {},
   loggedIn: false,
   currentUser: null,
   userProfile: {}
 }

 export default {
   namespaced: true,
   state
 }
```

auth.js:

```
import store from './store'
const fb = require('./firebaseConfig.js')

fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
 if (user) {
  fb.postsCollection.orderBy('createdOn', 'desc').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {

  let createdByCurrentUser
  if (querySnapshot.docs.length) {
    createdByCurrentUser = store.state.currentUser.uid === 
      querySnapshot.docChanges()[0].doc.data().userId ? 'Yes' : 'No'
    console.log(createdByCurrentUser)
   }
 })
 }
})
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from '@/store/user'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
   awesome: true
 },
 modules: {
  user
 }
})

export default store
```

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `getters`, take a look in the [doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

getters.js

```
export default {
  currentUser
}

function currentUser({ currentUser }) {
  return currentUser;
}
```

user.js

```
import getters from './getters'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    profile: {},
    loggedIn: false,
    currentUser: null,
    userProfile: {}
  },
  getters
}
```

auth.js

```
import store from './store';

const currentUser = store.getters['user/currentUser'];
```

Because you namespaced the module, you have to use it's name as a prefix to access the getter function

Comment: Did you replaced the `store.state.currentUser.uid` for `store.getters['user/currentUser'].uid`?

Comment: so is set: currentUser.uid === ...instead of store.state.currentUser.uid

Comment: so I set the const name currentUser (const currentUser = store.getters['user/currentUser'];)

Comment: maybe in the world component where I have set mapState?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181822/discussion-between-lukas-and-giovane).